# Сравнение DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Как сравнивать `DateTime` текущего момента с заранее известным `DateTime` с точностью до минуты?

Comment: А какой результат должен быть при сравнении 0 минут 59 секунд и 1 минуты 1 секунды? Разница между ними 2 секунды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[На англоязычной версии этого сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7029502) есть решение в виде отрезания значимых единиц во DateTime. На мой взгляд, вполне нормальное решение с возможностью дальнейшего расширения.

```
 public static DateTime TruncateTo(this DateTime dt, DateTruncate TruncateTo)
    {
        if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Year)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, 0, 0);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Month)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 0);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Day)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Hour)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Minute)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0);
        else 
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);

    }
    public enum DateTruncate
    {
        Year,
        Month,
        Day,
        Hour,
        Minute,
        Second
    }
```

Comment: Вы теряете `DateTime.Kind`.

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
using System;
static class Ex
{
    static public int CompareWithoutSeconds(this DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        if (d1.Minute == d2.Minute && d1.Hour == d2.Hour && d1.Date == d2.Date)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return d1.CompareTo(d2);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2009, 12, 11, 13, 35, 48, 95);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2009, 12, 11, 13, 35, 44, 67);
        int c = d1.CompareWithoutSeconds(d2);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

**UPD**
Вот ещё клевый вариант:

```
var d1 = DateTime.Now;
var d2 = new DateTime(2016, 04, 11, 15, 14, 01, 0);
bool equal = d1.ToString("g") == d2.ToString("g");
```

Comment: в UPD реально клевый вариант)

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron: Не слишком клёвый. Лишняя аллокация строки + полагается на текущую локаль.